# How to show whether limit of this function exists or does not exist?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The function is
$$f(x,y)=\frac{2x}{x^2+x+y^2}$$
I want to check whether
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)$$
exists or does not exist. I tried in polar coordinates and get the function
$$f(r, \theta)=\frac{2\cos\theta}{r(1+\cos\theta)}$$
I don't know how to proceed because $$\lim_{r\to0} f(r,\theta)$$ is not define.
Also I choose the curve $y=kx$ and I get 
$$f(x,y)=\frac{2}{x(1+k)+1}$$ which is also not define as $(x,y)$ approaches to (0,0). I think the limit value of the fuction does not exist but my question is "How to show using two path test for limit that limiting value of the function does not exist?"
Any path suggestion?

Comment: Do the iterated limits and see what happens!

Answer (score 1):

1)$y=0$, $ x \not =0$.

$\dfrac {2x}{x(x+1)}= \dfrac{2}{x+1}.$

Take the limit $x \rightarrow 0.$

2)$y \not = 0$, $x = 0.$

$\dfrac{0}{y^2}=0.$

Limit does not exist.